# Backbone: pluck models with an array of IDs, and save them

Tags: backbone.js

So I have an array of IDs:

`var myIDs = [1,5,9]`;

I have a collection that I want to search through, and pluck from. I thought I could do something like the following:

`var searchResults = myCollection.where({"uID" : myIDs});`

Of course that won't work, but there must be a way to achieve something similar.

Once I have the selected models, the plan is to edit the contents of, then save. Am I correct in assuming I can save the whole batch by doing the following?

`myCollection.reset(searchResults);`

I'm a total n00b to Backbone, obviously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Collection.filter`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) to compare each item against the array:

```
var searchResults = myCollection.filter(function(model) { 
    return myIDs.indexOf(model.id) != -1;
});
```

("Where" is like a special case of "filter", with a specific iterator -- it compares the properties of each model with the hash set you provide.)

As far as saving, if you mean replacing the items in the collection, then yes, you can use `reset` for that.  (Note that "save" in Backbone parlance normally means syncing model updates back to the server.)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. And yeah, sorry I mean, "reset to the collection, and save the collection." Coming from an MVC like Cake where you just manipulate an array and save it, Backbone's a bit of a paradigm shift. :)